# Pytorch parameters won't update with custom loss function (Pytorch)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use the optimizer to tune a set of parameters for a cost function that includes, among other things, a forward pass across a neural network. The parameters specify the means and variances of the weights of this neural network. However, when updating the parameters at every iteration of the optimization process, all the terms of the cost function except the one belonging to the forward pass contribute to the parameter update. That is, if all other terms are commented out, no parameters will update. Are there any ways of fixing this issue?

EDIT: I added a contrived example below.

```py
import torch

class TestNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestNN, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x

    def getParameters(self):
        return [self.fc1.weight.transpose(0, 1), self.fc1.bias]

    def setParameters(self, parameters):
        # Can anything be done here to keep parameters in the graph?
        weight, bias = parameters
        self.fc1.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(weight.transpose(0, 1))
        self.fc1.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(bias)

def computeCost(parameters, input):
    testNN = TestNN()
    testNN.setParameters(parameters)
    cost = testNN(input) ** 2
    print(cost) # Cost stays the same :(
    return cost

def minimizeLoss(maxIter, optimizer, lossFunc, lossFuncArgs):
    for i in range(maxIter):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = lossFunc(*lossFuncArgs)
        loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
        optimizer.step()
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(loss)

input = torch.randn(1, 10)
weight = torch.ones(10, 1)
bias = torch.ones(1, 1)

parameters = (weight, bias)
lossArgs = (parameters, input)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(parameters, lr = 0.01)

minimizeLoss(10, optimizer, computeCost, lossArgs)
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to be able to help you, but you need to specify a bit more. What is your cost function? Can you give a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @iacolippo Thanks for reaching out! I added a small example. Essentially, I would like to train a cost function as shown. However, in the actual case I will be setting the weights of my neural network repeatedly based on the same parameters (which will represent the mean and variance of the weights).

Comment: @JKB cost is merely the output of the network squared, are you trying to do mean square?? I mean I am not sure I am able to understand what would squaring the output or prediction alone of network do, shouldn't it be prediction - true value or some comparison with the real values of this kind instead of just a square of the output or prediction alone ?

Comment: @Inder The square is just an arbitrary example. Essentially, for this example, I would want the parameters to change so that the loss yields an output of zero for the provided input. However, the cost is not changing :(

Comment: In some use cases it is required to define the backward function as well, you can look at the details with an example here https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/extending.html